# How to create a homepage exposed views search box drupal 7

Tags: views

I'm sure this is really easy to do, but I've spent the best part of 2 hours trying to get Views to accomodate and I'm stuck.

Simply, I would like to create a single search function using Views in Drupal 7 which can go on a homepage to search for both "subject" and "town/ZIP" (ie "English Teachers" available in "Detroit". then the user hits the GO button. This will search the node fields and return a list which (ala a general google search engine style). I'm ambitious in moving forward with D7, but it's painfully slow at the moment).

OK, I'm new to D7 but not IT, but the lack of helpful books or tutorials is making self-learning takes 'years' and not 'months' (I'm upskilling during this downturn and I need to get back into employment like now not next year!).

Can anyone point me to a decent 'How to' tutorial for the above, or suggest the real easy way option in Views? I'd rather use Views and not have any .tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add filters for this fields to your view.
2. Mark this filters as exposed.
3. Go to blocks and make sure your exposed filter is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Views filters populate](http://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate) to use one exposed string filter to search on multiple fields.

Comment: I recommend "Learn Views with NodeOne" series http://vimeo.com/21051899.

Comment: What I'm really loking for is to create like this: http://www.thomsonlocal.com/ EXACTLY!!